# How to save a weighted data from r svydesign package?

Tags: r, survey

Is there a way to save weighted data so next time I directly load it? I have a large survey dataset, and use R's `survey` package. I load the data with `feather` package, but it takes considerable time when I apply svydesign. Here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(20, 0, 1), col2 = rnorm(20, 2, 2), w = rnorm(20, 1, .2))
df.w <- svydesign(id = ~1, data = df, weights = ~w)
```

I want to save **df.w** and use this for future analysis. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `saveRDS` and `readRDS` to save/read single `R` objects like this.

```
library(survey)

df <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(20, 0, 1), col2 = rnorm(20, 2, 2), w = rnorm(20, 1, .2))
df.w <- svydesign(id = ~1, data = df, weights = ~w)

####### save to file ##########
storage_file <- tempfile()
#storage_file <- "mydesign.rds"   ## uncomment here to use a local file
saveRDS(df.w, storage_file)

######## clear workspace #########
rm(df, df.w)

######### load the data ###########
df.w.loaded <- readRDS(storage_file)

df.w.loaded
## Independent Sampling design (with replacement)
## svydesign(id = ~1, data = df, weights = ~w)

######## delete storage file ######
file.remove(storage_file)
```

If you want to save several objects in a single file, take a look at `?save` and `?load`.

Comment: And in case it's not obvious to future readers, the temp directory is cleared when R closes, so this exact code should not be used even though saveRDS() is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks Gregor and Thomas. Although using rds format makes is simpler, but it is doesn't improve loading time. I compared timing and I found read_feather+svydesign to run considerably faster than saveRDS+loadRDS (or write_rds+read_rds from readr package); including non-compressed rds. Am I missing anything?

Comment: hi, the `saveRDS` parameter `compress = FALSE` requires more disk space but improves loading speed